# How can I make sure that the GNU linker ld is page aligning sections without a linker script?

Tags: ld

As the title suggests, I'm trying to compile and subsequently link a binary, and I want the sections (text, data, bss, etc.) to be paged-aligned. To achieve that, I'm trying to pass the `--no-omagic`option to `ld`. The literal command I'm using (in my Makefile) is:

```
ld --no-omagic -o build/initlink.out $^
```

`ld --help` says the option should have the following effect:

```
--no-omagic        Page align data, make text readonly
```

But if I do an `nm -n` on the output, the first symbol in each section is *not* aligned. For example:

```
$ nm -n build/initlink.out | grep ' [tT] ' | head -n 1
00000000004000f0 T main

$ nm -n build/initlink.out | grep ' [dD] ' | head -n 1
00000000006d74b0 d vsscanf.basefix

$ nm -n build/initlink.out | grep ' [bB] ' | head -n 1
00000000006e7200 B __bss_start
```

If it's important, one thing with which I'm trying to link is a static library (`.a` extension).

Is there anything that I could be doing wrong? Is there another way to ensure page alignment of sections, *without* resorting to a linker script? I've tried using the `--section-alignment` option, but when I do, I'm told that it's unrecognized. The static library defines some strange symbols (involving "linker sets," which I've found to be woefully undocumented) with which I was running into issues, so I want to try to do this without having to do anything but tell the linker to put sections in certain places.